# How do you hide tool tips in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to hide the tool tips that popup when you hover over objects? Especially when you hover over tables, I do not want to see the breakdown of what objects are in that table.

Comment: Topic off. Ask your question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Philip Olson on the mysql.com bug system](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72257), this is "fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.1.6 release".

Comment: I just installed the new release and they have addressed the issue.